# @media query not applying styles like expected?

Tags: css, typescript, media-queries

I'm trying to apply different styles to my modal based on the screen size being below a certain pixel size.

What I have done looks like this:

```
const ModalContainer = styled(T.TextBodyRegular4)`
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
  background: ${theme.color.surface[100]};
  border: 1px solid ${theme.color.surface[300]};
  box-shadow: 0px ${theme.spacing.pixel["050"]} ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]}
    rgba(35, 51, 45, 0.16);
  border-radius: ${theme.spacing.pixel["050"]};
  transition: width 500ms ease-in-out 0s, height 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll !important;

  &.silo-modal-fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &.silo-modal-small {
    @media (max-width: ${BP.XS}px) {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      position: absolute;
      top: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      bottom: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
    }
    width: min(calc(${theme.spacing.pixel[1000]} * 2), 100%);
  }

  &.silo-modal-medium {
    @media (max-width: ${BP.XS}px) {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      position: absolute;
      top: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      bottom: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
    }
    width: min(calc(${theme.spacing.pixel[1000]} * 2 + 100px), 100%);
  }

  &.silo-modal-large {
    @media (max-width: ${BP.XS}px) {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      position: absolute;
      top: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      bottom: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
    }
    width: min(calc(${theme.spacing.pixel[1000]} * 4), 100%);
    & > ${ModalFooter} {
      max-width: calc(
        ${theme.spacing.pixel[750]} * 2 + ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]}
      );
      align-self: end;
    }
  }

  &.silo-modal-auto {
    @media (max-width: ${BP.XS}px) {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      position: absolute;
      top: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
      bottom: ${theme.spacing.pixel[150]};
    }
    width: auto;
  }

  p {
    ${ModalScrollContent};
  }
`;
```

I'm thinking that for starters, there's probably a way to write this in a more neat manner.
Regardless though, these styles aren't being applied. I'd like the positioning to change to absolute, and change the margins and introduce top and bottom properties. When I inspect the element in chrome, I don't see those properties anywhere - they're not even being overwritten, they just don't exist.

Am I misusing the @media queries?

Comment: `@media (max-width: ${BP.XS}px)` `{&.silo-modal-large{   }  }`

Comment: first write @media then elements inside

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp